# how to fix/work-around cr/lf / LF no longer working in dev tools console

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

[honestly, this is a WTF for chromium project once again fixing something that wasn't broken -- until a recent update to chromium-based browsers (it shows up in Chrome 91 and Edge 91, but does not manifest itself in Opera 60, nor the latest Firefox)]

To wit: previously, the console would honor/interpret LF  (ie \n ) in a character string written to the console log.  for  example, if you entered

xyz="\nabc\ndef\ng"
the console would display ->

```
"
abc
def
g"
```

Now it displays:
"\nabc\ndef\ng"

This totally bollixes all of the embedded functions previously written to be invoked from the console that are intended to write to the console log.
Using \n in output to console log has been promoted on this forum for nearly a decade.
So, is this a new 'feature' or a bug?

Comment: Use console.log("\nabc\ndef\ng")

Comment: The problem is - that exact method not longer works in Chrome/Edge 91 but does in Opera/Firefox.
```
dfsdk.manifest("*", 32)
"\n'node'      : var DF_STATE       = 32      // state/feedback node (no event propagation)\n'attachment': var DF_AREPLACE    = 32      // string->innerHTML / docFragment->doc node's subtree\n'datastore' : var DF_STATE          = 32             // datastore used for 'state' data\n"
```
dfsdk.manifest calls console.log just as you suggest; but the above is just what comes out now.

Comment: Chromium/Chrome's devtools has changed it intentionally. The other browsers didn't.

Comment: So, do I have to add an intercept, and parse-out of the \n and generate individual calls to console.log?   Although feasible, what I have found is the lots of individual calls to console.log >really< slow down the main thread as the log appears to behave as if it is a linked list.?

Comment: console.log already displays `\n` as an actual new line so all you need to do is to use console.log instead of relying on the implicit heuristics of devtools when it parses the result of the executed JS expression.

Comment: thank you (always appreciate your comments and suggestions - sorry I was a little slow on the uptake)